# PHP - Google pagerank unique visitors

Tags: php, pagerank

i've been using the compete api to access the unique visitors of a given url.. i.e

http://apps.compete.com/sites/facebook.com/trended/uv/?apikey=f14c3daf29e92699e1ac1c0dcd70fa7b

works fine but the above have a 'daily limit' for using the api key..i've tried searching but have not yet found a suitable method or piece of code that returns the unique visitors for a particular site..any help??

Comment: This is not for sites you own, is it?  You're wanting to be able to check the traffic for arbitrary sites?

Comment: i'm actually working on google page rank given a keyword(any) ,where i obtain the page rank and the url (based on a given keyword)..my wish is now to return the unique visitors for a given site returned

Comment: I see, are you paying for the account with Compete?

Comment: using the free package.expires after like 10 queries..